# "Eu me chamo" or "eu chamo-me"?

Tags: colocação-pronominal, pronomes-reflexivos

Given these two possible word orders for using the reflexive pronoun:

1. Eu **me** chamo.
2. Eu chamo-**me**.

Are both those versions correct as written?

Under what circumstances would one version be preferred over the other and why, or is there no difference and the two of them are used completely interchangeably by all speakers and writers?

Comment: See [here](http://alfclul.clul.ul.pt/wochwel/documents/Cl%C3%ADticos_Gram%C3%A1tica%20do%20Portugu%C3%AAs_Gulbenkian.pdf) for a chapter on clitic positioning in the European variety.

Comment: That site is blocked by Malwarebytes.....we say reflexive pronoun in English, by the way.....

Answer (score 5):

Depende da variante da língua:

## Portugal

> Eu chamo-me.

## Brasil

> Eu me chamo.

Considerando que em português, tal como em espanhol, o pronome pessoal enquanto sujeito pode ser omitido, a palavra *eu*, neste caso, pode também ser omitida da frase.

Comment: `Considerando que em Português, tal como em Espanhol, o pronome pessoal enquanto sujeito pode ser omitido, a palavra "eu", neste caso, pode também ser omitida da frase.` Isso é verdade, mas para brasileiros, especialmente na língua falada, isso soa estranho.

Comment: @Renan será assim tão estranho um brasileiro referir oralmente `me chamo João` ? Em Portugal é perfeitamente banal dizer `chamo-me João`.

Comment: Sim, na maior parte do Brasil. Existem alguns lugares onde se fala assim, mas são minoria.

Answer (score 1):

No Brasil, a variante *Eu me chamo* é utilizada. Esse caso é um exemplo da colocação pronominal em próclise, onde o pronome vem antes do verbo.

A estrutura também é válida quando conjugada em outras pessoas e tempos verbais: *ela se chama* / *meu avô se chamava*melhorei a formatação.

Answer (score 1):

Both expressions are correct Standard Portuguese, both in Brazil and in Portugal. But "Eu chamo-me" is preferred in Portugal, and very unusual in Brazil. In colloquial Portuguese, only "Eu me chamo" is used in Brazil.

In Standard Portuguese, the expression "Me chamo", without the pronoun, is deemed incorrect (if there are no other words in the sentence before "me"). But it is very usual in colloquial Brazilian Portuguese¹. I suppose that "Chamo-me", with no pronoun (which is correct Standard Portuguese) is also very usual in colloquial European Portuguese.

If there are other words, especially adverbs, before "me", then a proclitic construction might be preferable, and even mandatory, in Standard Portuguese (and on both sides of the ocean):

> Eu não me chamo João.
>
> *Eu não chamo-me João.
>
> Ninguém sabe que me chamo João.
>
> *Ninguém sabe que chamo-me João.

But:

> Felizmente me chamo João.
>
> Felizmente chamo-me João.

---

#### Footnotes

1. This is true of all verbs, but especially of those forms where the last pre-vocalic consonant is the same as the initial consonant of the clitic, as is the case in "chamo-me" (or "chamaste-te") – the repetition of the sound is awkward for Brazilian sensibilities. "Chamava-me" or "chamas-te" would be marginally better received.